# Immediately invoked function expression invoking parenthesis

Tags: javascript

While working with IIFE found that both of these expression works

**Type:1**

```
(function() {
    //Rest of code
})();
```

**Type:2**

```
(function() {
    //Rest of Code
}());
```

Is there any formal difference between two?

Comment: Type:1 looks like "dogs balls" according to Douglas Crockford :p

Comment: Kindly always search before you ask. `:)` It has been asked a lot of times.